# Removing Bitlocker fom Surface Pro

Tags: linux, encryption, bitlocker, microsoft-surface, microsoft

I am new here. I am using a Microsoft Surface 5th generation and it was not going further after the login screen and it will not let me enter the password.

When i tried to reset it using Shift+restart option, it started asking for the bitlocker key. After i enter the bitlocker key it takes me to the same problem. If i try to reset it (using shift+restart option), it gave the error code 0x80070013. And i am not able to use my system.

Things i have tried so far-

1. I made a windows usb (not the surface image) and tried to format the disk in the installation screen and it gives me the error that bitlocker needs to be disabled from control panel.
2. Using diskpart, i tried to erase the disk but it gives me cyclic redundancy error (deleting both volume and disk).
3. I tried a surface image and resetting the device, it gives me the error,' there was a problem resetting your PC, no changes were made'.
   4.I tried dislocker in Linux and i was able to access the data but i cannot make any changes in order to remove bitlocker or change Magnify.exe to cmd in order to access cmd.

I have already tried contacting Microsoft and they have only provided me basic troubleshooting.
Thank you for reading the problem, hope someone has the solution.

Comment: A cyclic redundancy (CRC) error may indicate a hardware problem. You can try to use a bootable Linux USB stick and delete all partitions and then retry Windows installation. If that fails with an error something is wrong with your hardware.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the response. I have already tried deleting partition with linux but it says the disk is write protected so it cannot be deleted. I am guessing the issue is with the SSD.